# Android: How to fetch Facebook Page Note using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch a note data using Facebook Graph API, and I found that the one available is now deprecated, is there another alternative?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no alternative, it was removed a long time ago with v2.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: @luschn Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tobi: did you comment in the wrong thread? I don´t know what you mean :)